# How to set Akka actors run only for specific time period?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I have a big task,which i break down into smaller task and analyse them. I have a basic model.

Master,worker and listener .

Master creates the tasks,give them to worker actors. Once an worker actor completes,it asks for another task from the master. Once all task is completed ,they inform the listener. They usually take around less than 2 minutes to complete 1000 tasks.

Now,Some time the time taken for some tasks might be more than others. **I want to set timer for each task,and if a task takes more time,then worker task should be aborted by the master and the task has to be resubmitted later as new one.** How to implement this? I can calculate the time taken by a worker task,but how Master actor keeps tab on time taken by all worker actors in real time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of handling this would be for each worker, on receipt of a task to start on, sets a timeout before changing state to process the task, eg:

```
  context.setReceiveTimeout(5 minutes)  // for the '5 minutes' notation - import scala.concurrent.duration._
```

If the timeout is received, the worker can abort the task (or whatever other action you deem appropriate - eg. kill itself, or pass a notification message back to the master). Don't forget to cancel the timeout (set duration = Duration.Undefined) if the task is completed or the like.

Comment: This will only be a viable option if the worker is not doing the work itself; basically being a lightweight proxy to another actor where the work is performed.  That way all this worker does it make the request to do the work to the other actor and then switch state to waiting for the response (using `setReceiveTimeout` to handle no response within certain time).  If the worker was performing some kind of synchronous work itself, then you can't really interrupt it in the way you describe and you'd be left managing timeouts from the master.

Comment: Ah, yes - you are quite right @cmbaxter. I was basing my answer on actors I am familiar with that used this idea and indeed those actors _are_ handling their tasks by coordinating calls to other actors. Still, having each 'worker' be a kind of wrapper around a child actor that does the actual (synchronous) work might be viable.